# Embedding Facebook video into html webpage dosnt work

Tags: html, facebook

I have done it correctly (i think) 
however, nothing shows up. I followed this https://www.facebook.com/help/1570724596499071?helpref=uf_permalink and it didn't work. Then followed this https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-video-player and did what it said only to find that it still didn't work.

Code:

```
`<!docutype html>

<html>

<head>

</head>
<body bgColor="grey"> 
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<br>
<div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/FacebookDevelopers" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin" data-height="The pixel height of the plugin" data-colorscheme="light" data-show-faces="true" data-header="true" data-stream="true" data-show-border="true"></div>
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/video.php?href=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2FSydneyBodyboardClub%2Fvideos%2F1362643443797235%2F&show_text=0&width=560" width="560" height="311" style="border:none;overflow:hidden" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" allowTransparency="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
</body>

</html>`
```

Comment: Or you testing this on a page you call via `http://` or `https://` in your browser? Have you checked the browser console for errors?

Comment: connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=207087449372135 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND                                                       that's the error /\

Comment: So that means the answer to my first question would neither of those? In that case: https://stackoverflow.com/q/44355919/1427878